# UITableViewCell not displaying constraints as intended

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to programatically create a tableview cell, but having some trouble getting it to layout as intended. I think its down to the order I call things but I cant get the content to display as intended (ive tried the insets and other constraints on a uiview and it seemed to work ok).

Im registering the tableview cell in the VC, Im also dequeuing a reusable cell in cellforrow where I pass the activity object to update the cell UI. The cell has a height of 300 set by the heightforrow callback.

ActivityCell code

```
class ActivityCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private var activityCard = UIView()
    private var verticalStack = UIStackView()
    private var nameStack = UIStackView()      // top horizontal stack
    private let profileImage = UIImageView()
    private let profileNameLbl = UILabel()
    private let dateLbl = UILabel()
    private let raceVerticalStack = UIStackView()  //middle
    private let topRaceStack = UIStackView()
    private let bottomRaceStack = UIStackView()
    private let raceNameStack = UIStackView()
    private let raceNameLbl = UILabel()
    private let distanceStack = UIStackView()
    private let distanceLbl = UILabel()
    private let distanceValueLbl = UILabel()
    private let timeStack = UIStackView()
    private let timeLbl = UILabel()
    private let timeValueLbl = UILabel()
    private let paceStack = UIStackView()
    private let paceLbl = UILabel()
    private let paceValueLbl = UILabel()
    private let positionStack = UIStackView()
    private let positionLbl = UILabel()
    private let positionValueLbl = UILabel()
    private let pointsStack = UIStackView()
    private let pointsLbl = UILabel()
    private let pointsValueLbl = UILabel()
    private let bottomStack = UIStackView()  //bottom
    private let clapStack = UIStackView()
    private let clapIcon = UIImageView()
    private let clapCountLbl = UILabel()
    private let clapCommentStack = UIStackView()
    private let commentStack = UIStackView()
    private let commentIcon = UIImageView()
    private let commentCountLbl = UILabel()
    private let clapButton = UIButton()     // interaction buttons
    private let commentButton = UIButton()
    
    
    private let gradientStart = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 44/255, blue: 86/255, alpha: 1.0)
    private let gradientEnd = UIColor(red: 234/255, green: 82/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1.0)
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        activityCard.frame = self.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
        verticalStack.frame = activityCard.frame
        
        setupHierarchy()
        setConstraints()
        configureView()
        
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configureView() {
        labelSetup()
        buttonSetup()
        stackViewSetup()
        imageSetup()
        stackViewSetup()
        setShadow()
    }

    func updateCell(with activity: RaceActivity) {
        profileNameLbl.text = activity.runnerName
        profileImage.image = activity.profileImage
        raceNameLbl.text = activity.raceName
        distanceValueLbl.text = activity.distance
        timeValueLbl.text = activity.time
        paceValueLbl.text = activity.pace
        positionValueLbl.text = activity.position
        pointsValueLbl.text = activity.points
    }
    
    private func labelSetup() {
        profileNameLbl.font = .Graphik()
        raceNameLbl.font = .Graphik(.medium, size: 22)
        dateLbl.font = .Graphik(.light, size: 17)
        distanceLbl.font = .Graphik()
        timeLbl.font = .Graphik()
        paceLbl.font = .Graphik()
        positionLbl.font = .Graphik()
        pointsLbl.font = .Graphik()
        clapCountLbl.font = .Graphik()
        commentCountLbl.font = .Graphik()
        paceLbl.font = .Graphik()
        distanceValueLbl.font = .Graphik(.medium)
        timeValueLbl.font = .Graphik(.medium)
        paceValueLbl.font = .Graphik(.medium)
        positionValueLbl.font = .Graphik(.medium)
   
        timeLbl.textAlignment = .left
        paceLbl.textAlignment = .center
        paceValueLbl.textAlignment = .center
        pointsLbl.textAlignment = .left
        pointsValueLbl.textAlignment = .left
        dateLbl.textAlignment = .right
        clapCountLbl.text = "33"
        commentCountLbl.text = "12"
        positionLbl.text = "Position"
        pointsLbl.text = "Points"
        distanceLbl.text = "Distance"
        timeLbl.text = "Time"
        paceLbl.text = "Pace"
        dateLbl.text = "Friday"
    }
    
    private func stackViewSetup() {
        nameStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        topRaceStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        bottomRaceStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        clapCommentStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        bottomStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        raceNameStack.axis = .horizontal
        nameStack.axis = .horizontal
        verticalStack.axis = .vertical
        raceVerticalStack.axis = .vertical
        bottomStack.axis = .horizontal
        topRaceStack.axis = .horizontal
        bottomRaceStack.axis = .horizontal
        distanceStack.axis = .vertical
        timeStack.axis = .vertical
        paceStack.axis = .vertical
        positionStack.axis = .vertical
        pointsStack.axis = .vertical
        
        nameStack.spacing = 10
        verticalStack.spacing = 5
        raceVerticalStack.spacing = 10
        bottomStack.spacing = 10
        
        nameStack.alignment = .center
        distanceStack.alignment = .center
        timeStack.alignment = .center
        paceStack.alignment = .center
        pointsStack.alignment = .center
        positionStack.alignment = .center
        clapCommentStack.alignment = .center
        bottomStack.alignment = .center
        
        raceVerticalStack.spacing = 5
        topRaceStack.spacing = 2
        clapCommentStack.spacing = 3
        clapStack.spacing = 4
        commentStack.spacing = 4
    }
    
    private func buttonSetup() {
        clapButton.setTitle("Clap", for: .normal)
        clapButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
        clapButton.titleLabel?.font = .Graphik(.regular, size: 14)
        clapButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        clapButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 30)
        clapButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "clap"), for: .normal)
        commentButton.setTitle("Comment", for: .normal)
        commentButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
        commentButton.titleLabel?.font = .Graphik(.regular, size: 14)
        commentButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        commentButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        commentButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "comment"), for: .normal)
    }
    
    private func imageSetup() {
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        profileImage.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        clapIcon.image = UIImage(named: "clapGrey")
        clapIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        commentIcon.image = UIImage(named: "commentGrey")
        commentIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
 
    
    private func setShadow() {

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 5), size: frame.size)
        gradient.colors = [gradientStart.cgColor, gradientEnd.cgColor]

        let border = CAShapeLayer()
        border.lineWidth = 2
        border.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 2, bottom: 10, right: 22)), cornerRadius: 12).cgPath
        border.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        border.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradient.mask = border
        removeExistingGradient(from: self)
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
        
    }
    
    private func setConstraints() {
        
        let constraints = [
            nameStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            raceNameStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            topRaceStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            bottomRaceStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            commentButton.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 90),
            clapButton.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 90),
            clapIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),
            commentIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
        setupMargins()
    }
    
    private func setupMargins() {
        nameStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 25)
        raceNameStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        raceVerticalStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 35)
        bottomStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 30)
        nameStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        topRaceStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        bottomRaceStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        raceNameStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        bottomStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        addLines()
    }
    
    private func addLines() {
        guard bottomStack.frame.height > 0 else { return }
        let horizontalStart = CGPoint(x: bottomStack.frame.minX, y: bottomStack.frame.minY)
        let bottomLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: horizontalStart.x + 20, y: horizontalStart.y + 12, width: bottomStack.frame.width - 40, height: 1.0))
        bottomLine.tag = 99
        bottomLine.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        bottomLine.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        let clapStackLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: clapCommentStack.frame.maxX, y: horizontalStart.y + 22, width: 1.0, height: clapCommentStack.frame.maxY - clapCommentStack.frame.minY))
        clapStackLine.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        clapStackLine.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        let commentLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: clapButton.frame.maxX, y: horizontalStart.y + 22, width: 1.0, height: clapCommentStack.frame.maxY - clapCommentStack.frame.minY))
        commentLine.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        commentLine.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        let topLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: horizontalStart.x + 20, y: nameStack.frame.maxY + 5, width: bottomStack.frame.width - 40, height: 1.0))
        topLine.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        topLine.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.activityCard.addSubview(bottomLine)
        self.activityCard.addSubview(clapStackLine)
        self.activityCard.addSubview(commentLine)
        self.activityCard.addSubview(topLine)
    }
    
    
    private func setupHierarchy() {
        nameStack.addArrangedSubview(profileImage)
        nameStack.addArrangedSubview(profileNameLbl)
        nameStack.addArrangedSubview(dateLbl)
        
        raceVerticalStack.addArrangedSubview(raceNameStack)
        raceVerticalStack.addArrangedSubview(topRaceStack)
        raceVerticalStack.addArrangedSubview(bottomRaceStack)
        
        raceNameStack.addArrangedSubview(raceNameLbl)
        
        topRaceStack.addArrangedSubview(distanceStack)
        topRaceStack.addArrangedSubview(timeStack)
        topRaceStack.addArrangedSubview(paceStack)
        
        bottomRaceStack.addArrangedSubview(positionStack)
        bottomRaceStack.addArrangedSubview(pointsStack)
        bottomRaceStack.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
        
        distanceStack.addArrangedSubview(distanceLbl)
        distanceStack.addArrangedSubview(distanceValueLbl)
        timeStack.addArrangedSubview(timeLbl)
        timeStack.addArrangedSubview(timeValueLbl)
        paceStack.addArrangedSubview(paceLbl)
        paceStack.addArrangedSubview(paceValueLbl)
        positionStack.addArrangedSubview(positionLbl)
        positionStack.addArrangedSubview(positionValueLbl)
        pointsStack.addArrangedSubview(pointsLbl)
        pointsStack.addArrangedSubview(pointsValueLbl)
        
        clapStack.addArrangedSubview(clapIcon)
        clapStack.addArrangedSubview(clapCountLbl)
        
        commentStack.addArrangedSubview(commentIcon)
        commentStack.addArrangedSubview(commentCountLbl)
        
        clapCommentStack.addArrangedSubview(clapStack)
        clapCommentStack.addArrangedSubview(commentStack)
        
        mainStackHierarchy()
    }
    
    private func mainStackHierarchy() {
        bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(clapCommentStack)
        bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(clapButton)
        bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(commentButton)
        
        verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(nameStack)
        verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(raceNameStack)
        verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(raceVerticalStack)
        verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(bottomStack)
        activityCard.addSubview(verticalStack)
        self.contentView.addSubview(activityCard)
    }
}
```

---

screenshot of current output:

[image]

---

screenshot of intended output:

[image]

---

Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having problems because you're using a lot of explicit frames instead of taking advantage of auto-layout.

First, if you change your `init()` func to this and run your app:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    // no need to set frames
    //activityCard.frame = self.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
    //verticalStack.frame = activityCard.frame
    
    setupHierarchy()
    setConstraints()
    configureView()

    activityCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    verticalStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        activityCard.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
        activityCard.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
        activityCard.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
        activityCard.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),

        verticalStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityCard.topAnchor, constant: 6.0),
        verticalStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityCard.leadingAnchor, constant: 6.0),
        verticalStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityCard.trailingAnchor, constant: -6.0),
        verticalStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityCard.bottomAnchor, constant: -6.0),

    ])
    
}
```

You'll see that you are much closer to what you want.

Next, change:

```
private var activityCard = UIView()
```

to:

```
private var activityCard = ActivityCardView()
```

and use this class:

```
class ActivityCardView: UIView {
    private let gradientStart = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 44/255, blue: 86/255, alpha: 1.0)
    private let gradientEnd = UIColor(red: 234/255, green: 82/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1.0)

    private let gradLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.addSublayer(gradLayer)
        gradLayer.colors = [gradientStart.cgColor, gradientEnd.cgColor]
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        gradLayer.frame = bounds
        
        let border = CAShapeLayer()
        border.lineWidth = 2
        border.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 2, bottom: 10, right: 2)), cornerRadius: 12).cgPath
        border.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        border.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradLayer.mask = border
    }
}
```

then, remove your `private func setShadow()` from the cell class. This `ActivityCardView` class will automatically handle the gradient border.

For your "separator" lines, you're probably much better off adding them as arranged subviews of your `verticalStack` than trying to position them with absolute coordinates:

```
private func mainStackHierarchy() {
    bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(clapCommentStack)
    bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(clapButton)
    bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(commentButton)
    
    verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(nameStack)
    
    var hLineView = UIView()
    hLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true
    hLineView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(hLineView)
    
    verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(raceNameStack)
    verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(raceVerticalStack)

    hLineView = UIView()
    hLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true
    hLineView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(hLineView)
    
    verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(bottomStack)
    activityCard.addSubview(verticalStack)
    self.contentView.addSubview(activityCard)
}
```

At this point, your output should look about like this:

[image]

The underline on the race name would probably best be handled by using attributed text with underline style.

I assume you'll want to make some adjustments to spacing -- but that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: thats brilliant! thank you so much I cant believe I overlooked creating a new class for the activity card. I guess I approached it thinking of storyboard design too much rather than using advantages of programmatically creating UI elements